# gmp error: cannot determine how to define a 32-bit word

Tags: macos, gmp, macos-mojave, nm

I'm trying to build the recent version of GMP 6.1.2 on macOS Mojave, but during `./configure` I get this:

```
$ ../configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-8.2 --enable-cxx gmp_cv_asm_underscore=yes
...
checking how to define a 32-bit word... /usr/local/bin/nm: conftest.o: unknown load command 0x32
/usr/local/bin/nm: conftest.o: unknown load command 0x32
/usr/local/bin/nm: conftest.o: file format not recognized
/usr/local/bin/nm: conftest.o: unknown load command 0x32
/usr/local/bin/nm: conftest.o: unknown load command 0x32
/usr/local/bin/nm: conftest.o: file format not recognized
configure: error: cannot determine how to define a 32-bit word
```

On the previous version of macOS GMP 6.1.0 built just fine. 
I freshly reinstalled developer tools via `xcode-select --install` and Xcode itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in faulty `nm`. It has a [bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23728) in the current version on macOS Mojave.